# Unhide Action Bar/Navigation Bar in Vuforia - Unity Project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-navigation-bar

I am trying to get the Action Bar in the Augmented Reality UnityPlayer camera view to remain visible (not hidden/lights out mode). We are working with Vuforia, Unity, and Android Studio to create an AR Experience within our app. Currently, I am building the AR scene in Unity, exporting the project to Android in build settings, and then converting the project to a library and setting it up in my application. I have gotten it to integrate well, but I would like the Android ActionBar to remain visible while the AR application is working. I have tried a variety of things, none of which have worked so far:

I have added a script with void Start() {Screen.fullScreen = false;}

I have changed android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen to android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

I have tried wrapping the UnityPlayerActivity in a Wrapper but since it is a library it has not worked well.

So far I've been playing with different options that would usually work in Android but none of them are having any effect.

Is there a way to have the navigation bar remain unconcealed?

Thank you

-Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Screen.fullScreen = !Screen.fullScreen;
```

Comment: This did not do anything for me. The screen did not change when called.